# How to give the reverse diagonal rows and columns color in a 2D array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

for school i have made an 2D array. All numbers that are diagonal needs to be the color red, which works. Now i want to print all reverse diagonal columns and rows yellow. Here is some code: In the method  DisplayMatrixWithCross it has to be made.

[image: Assignment:]

```
using System.Data.Common;

namespace assignment1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid number of arguments!");
                Console.WriteLine("usage: assignment[1-3] <nr of rows> <nr of columns>");
                return;
            }
            int numberOfRows = int.Parse(args[0]);
            int numberOfColumns = int.Parse(args[1]);
            Program myProgram = new Program();
            myProgram.Start(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        }
        void Start(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            int[,] matrix = new int[numberOfRows, numberOfColumns];
            
            InitMatrixLinear(matrix);
            DisplayMatrix(matrix);
            DisplayMatrixWithCross(matrix);

        }

        void InitMatrix2D(int[,] matrix)
        {
            int element = 1;
            for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                    matrix[r, c] = element++;
                }
            }
        }
        void DisplayMatrix(int[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++)
                {

                    Console.Write($"{matrix[r, c]:00} ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        void InitMatrixLinear(int[,] matrix)
        {
            int element = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                int r = (element - 1) / matrix.GetLength(0);
                int c = (element - 1) % matrix.GetLength(1);
                matrix[r, c] = element;
                element++;
            }
        }

        void DisplayMatrixWithCross(int[,] matrix)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int rows = 0; rows < matrix.GetLength(0); rows++)
            {
                for (int columns = 0; columns < matrix.GetLength(1); columns++)
                {
                    if (rows == columns)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.Write($"{matrix[rows, columns]:00} ");
                       
                        
                    }
                    /* else if ()
                     {

                         Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                     }*/
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Write($"{matrix[rows, columns]:00} ");
                      

                    }

 
                   
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

            }

           
            }
            


        }

        }

    



Cant get it to work sadly, can anyone help
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: The image works, ironically, the link to the google docs is unaccessable.
I recommend embedding the image so it's directly visible, then delete the link to the google doc, as it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Nice that is a good thing that it is visible. But this assignment is killing me lol

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the value that goes in each spot, no need to keep a separate counter variable:

```
void InitMatrix2D(int[,] matrix)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            matrix[r, c] = (r * matrix.GetLength(1)) + (c + 1);
        }
    }
}

void InitMatrixLinear(int[,] matrix)
{
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.Length; i++)
    {
        int r = i / matrix.GetLength(1);
        int c = i % matrix.GetLength(1);
        matrix[r, c] = (i+1);
    }
}
```

Next, you can use `matrix.Length` to determine the correct amount of zeroes to pad your numbers with:

```
void DisplayMatrix(int[,] matrix)
{
    int maxLength = matrix.Length.ToString().Length;
    String numFormat = new string('0', maxLength);

    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            Console.Write(matrix[r, c].ToString(numFormat) + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Lastly, for the reverse diagonal, if the one-based row number plus the zero-based column number equals the number of columns, then you can change the background to yellow:

```
void DisplayMatrixWithCross(int[,] matrix)
{
    int maxLength = matrix.Length.ToString().Length;
    String numFormat = new string('0', maxLength);

    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int rows = 0; rows < matrix.GetLength(0); rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < matrix.GetLength(1); columns++)
        {
            Console.ResetColor();
            if (rows == columns)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;                        
            }
            if ((rows+1)+columns == matrix.GetLength(1))
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            }
            Console.Write(" " + matrix[rows, columns].ToString(numFormat));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

My output:

[image]